# How to cover the following lines of code in Test Class

Tags: unit-test

This is my Test Class:

```
@isTest public class OppContactBatchTest {
    @isTest static void MyMethod(){
                
        OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole();
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name = 'Test';
        opp.StageName = 'Handoff';
        opp.CloseDate = System.today();
        insert opp;
        
        Contact con = new Contact();
        ocr.ContactId = con.id;
        con.LastName = 'James';
        con.Primary_Contact__c = True;
        insert con;

        ocr.Primary_Contact__c = True;
        ocr.ContactId = con.id;
        ocr.OpportunityId = opp.id;
        //con.Primary_Contact__c = True;
        //con.Primary_Contact__c = False;
        insert ocr;
        
        OpportunityContactRole ocr1 = new OpportunityContactRole();
        ocr1.Primary_Contact__c = True;
        ocr1.ContactId = con.id;
        ocr1.OpportunityId = opp.id;
        //con.Primary_Contact__c = True;
        //con.Primary_Contact__c = False;
        insert ocr1;
        
        List<OpportunityContactRole> Oppcon = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
        Oppcon = [select id, Primary_Contact__c, Contact.Primary_Contact__c from OpportunityContactRole where Contact.Primary_Contact__c = true and Primary_Contact__c = false];
        System.debug('oppcon size is:' +oppcon.size());
        Test.startTest();
        OppContactBatch bp = new OppContactBatch();
        ID jobid = Database.executeBatch(bp,200);
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

This is my batch class:

```
global class OppContactBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{
   
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select id, Primary_Contact__c, Contact.Primary_Contact__c from OpportunityContactRole where Contact.Primary_Contact__c = true and Primary_Contact__c = false]);
    }
   
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<OpportunityContactRole> oppCont)
    {
        list<OpportunityContactRole> oppConRole = new list<OpportunityContactRole>();//Not Covered
        try{
            for(OpportunityContactRole cRole : oppCont){ //Not Covered
                cRole.Primary_Contact__c = True; //Not Covered
                oppConRole.add(cRole);//Not Covered
            }if(!oppConRole.isEmpty()){//Not Covered
                system.debug('oppConRole size is:' +oppConRole.size());
               //List<Database.SaveResult> updateResults = Database.update(oppConRole, false);
               update oppConRole;
            }
            
        }Catch(Exception e){ //Not Covered
            system.debug('Exception occurred due to:' +e.getCause()+'Exception message'+e.getMessage()+'At line Number'+e.getStackTraceString());
        }
    }
   
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using below query in batch class start method.

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([select id, Primary_Contact__c, Contact.Primary_Contact__c from OpportunityContactRole where Contact.Primary_Contact__c = true and Primary_Contact__c = false]);
```

In this query you are using filter :

1. OCR.Primary_Contact__c = false AND
2. Contact.Primary_Contact__c = True

But in test class you are putting the "True" value for OCR.Primary_Contact__c.

That's why Start Method didn't get any records and Execute method not Covered.

Comment: But If I make OCR.Primary_Contact__c = False , then also it is not covering the Execute method. Can you tell me the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

When an execute() method is not covered; the clue is that the start() method is returning 0 records

Your `start()` method executes this query:

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([select id, Primary_Contact__c, Contact.Primary_Contact__c 
    from OpportunityContactRole 
    where Contact.Primary_Contact__c = true and Primary_Contact__c = false]);
```

So, you are looking for OCRs with Primary_Contact__c = true but parent `Contact.Primary_Contact__c` = false (i.e. - they are out of sync)

Thus, your mocked data needs to reflect this

```
Opportunity mockedOppo = new Opportunity(..);
insert mockedOppo;

Contact[] mockedContacts = new List<Contact> {
  new Contact(.., Primary_Contact__c = true),
  new Contact(.., Primary_Contact__c = true),
  new Contact(.., Primary_Contact__c = false),
  new Contact(.., Primary_Contact__c = false)
};
insert mockedContacts;

OpportunityContactRole[] mockedOcrs = new Lits<OpportunityContactRole> {
  new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId = mockedContacts[0].Id
                             OpportunityId = mockedOppo.Id,
                             Primary_Contact__c = true),
  new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId = mockedContacts[1].Id
                             OpportunityId = mockedOppo.Id,
                             Primary_Contact__c = false),
  new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId = mockedContacts[2].Id
                             OpportunityId = mockedOppo.Id,
                             Primary_Contact__c = true),
  new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId = mockedContacts[3].Id
                             OpportunityId = mockedOppo.Id,
                             Primary_Contact__c = false)
};
insert mockedOcrs;
```

Now you have every combination of Contact/OCR: true/true, true/false, false/true, false/false